# react-hook-form: validate field using an API call in the validation

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm working on the register component of my app (React front-end, Django back-end), and I'm having a little trouble fleshing out all the error handling when validating email addresses. The way I have my users table set up, both the user's email and username must be unique, and I have the uniqueness specified in my Django models, but now I'm working on the error handling in my React components to prevent the API from getting register requests with already used emails/usernames. I have a simple API call for both username and email, that takes the email/username and returns true or false depending on if the value exists in the users table.

The issue I'm having is the validation doesn't seem to be properly listening to the results of the validation's API call. The API call is working correctly, but the validation doesn't seem to change between valid and invalid email addresses.

Here is my function for checking the email's validity:

```
    const checkEmailExists = (email) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('email', email)
    axiosInstance
        .post('/user/checkemailexists/', formData)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data.isAvailable);
            return response.data.isAvailable;
        });
    };
```

And this is the form field for email

```
                <div>
                <label className="text-gray-600 font-medium block mt-4">Email Address</label>
                <input 
                    className="border-solid border-gray-300 border py-2 px-4 w-full rounded text-gray-700"
                    name="email_address" 
                    type= "email"
                    {...register('email_address', { 
                        required: { value: true, message: "This field is required"}, 
                        validate: {
                            checkEmailExists: (value) => checkEmailExists(value) || "This email address is already in use",
                        }
                    })}
                />
                {errors.email_address && (
                <div className="mb-3 text-normal text-red-500">
                    {errors.email_address.message}
                </div>
                )}
                </div>
```

At the moment I have the form set to mode: "onSubmit" and reValidateMode: "onSubmit", but I don't think that matters too much for this.

What I ~think~ might be this issue is something to do with the synchronization between the validation happening and the API call that is made for that validation, maybe the validation is coming back before the API call does, so my results are being wonky? I'm not quite skilled enough at the moment to figure this out myself, and there doesn't seem to be too much on this from my searching, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check your API in the browser console or debugger - `response.data.isAvailable === "true"` is suspicious, because I would expect `response.data.isAvailable === true` (or, simplified, `return response.data.isAvailable`) - in other words, your API should be returning an actual boolean.

Async validation ought to work; see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-async-field-validation-forked-pbiqph?file=/src/index.js) for an example.

Showing an error message won't work as you expect; `checkEmailExists` returns a promise, which is truthy (it's a promise, not null/false/undefined), so `"This email address is already in use"` is never evaluated. Instead, move `"This email address is already in use"` within your checkEmailExists or a `.then` block.

Comment: I updated my API to return an actual boolean, and updated checkEmailExists in my post to reflect it, but it didn't change the behavior I'm currently getting. How would I add the error message inside my checkEmailExists function to then display? I'm only really familiar with how the error messages show up in the 'required' and 'validate' parts of my form field

Comment: @Chowdahhh, if you're able to put together a CodeSandbox demonstrating your form (with a stubbed-out API, similar to the link I gave), it would help others see what's going on. I believe you can change your validate function to return `return response.data.isAvailable || "My Error Message"`, but I haven't tested.

Comment: Sure, I threw together my form [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-meninsky-vegxsq?file=/src/App.js) I'm not super familiar with what the proper way to stub-out my API call would be, so I just changed the function to a simple `email !== "email@gmail.com"` check, but this does work as intended. If I switch it back to the commented out code in the checkEmailExists function, it won't work properly. If I run it as my main post shows, I will get the error message regardless of validity, and if I move `|| "This email address is already in use"` inside the function, I get no error regardless

Comment: And for a little more info, I'm confident that my API call functions properly. I've tested it through Postman, and despite the error handling not working properly, the console.log I have in the .then portion of the checkEmailExist function (line 37) properly gives true or false

Comment: @Chowdahhh - Thanks for putting together the demo. I see the problem now (and should have seen it sooner) - your validation function doesn't actually return anything, so as far as React Hook Form can tell, there's no validation problem. (The Axios promise resolves off in the background sometime in the future and doesn't do anything with its return value.) If you instead return the Axios promise (`return axiosInstance.post`...), things should work better.

Comment: That's it! It's working perfectly now. One last question, VS Code is suggesting I convert it to an async function, and do the API call like this `const response = await axiosInstance
            .post('/user/checkemailexists/', formData);` and then just return `response.data.isAvailable`. Functionally this doesn't seem to be any different to me, both work, but is one way considered to be more of a best practice over the other?

Comment: @Chowdahhh - `async` / `await` is generally considered more readable than promises, but it's generally up to you. (They're equivalent; in fact, tools like Babel will implement `async` / `await` using promises.)